# Java input and output streams

Tags: java

What are System.in and System.out in java a java program ? I know how to use them but the way '.' Operator is used seems like object in/out is static in nature even though I didn't get it .

Comment: Yes they are static, and they are used for reading inputs from console or outputting something to the console. Usually great for debugging purposes.

Comment: Great because it is included OOTB but not the best, I recommend you to use logger for debug purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are, effectively, flukes of history. Nothing else in the entire java language is quite like them; for learning java it is best to just accept that they are like this, and aren't like any other things, and it doesn't quite matter.

### Beware - if you must know

`out`, `err` and `in` are all `public static` fields in the `java.lang.System` class. They are marked `final`, so `System.out = null;` isn't legal, but they aren't actually final (in that they can be changed). The support for changing them is a hack that is applied by `System.setOut`. This method calls into native code (that's a java method which is implemented in C/assembler, i.e. an implementation straight for the platform your VM is running on, every architecture java on has its own implementation of these).

This is, in a word, a preposterous way to do it, but that's how it was done.

### So why is that legal java?

The syntax itself is nothing special, although not advised and therefore, you rarely see it. Imagine you have this:

```
public class Example {
    public static final List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
}

class MyCode {
    void whatever() {
       Example.foo.add("Hello!");
    }
}
```

This compiles and runs fine; `Example` refers to the Example class, `Example.foo` refers to the public field named `foo` inside it, and `Example.foo.add` is dereferencing that field to find the arraylist that this field is pointing at, and invoking that list's `add` method.

The problem with this is that public fields are 'icky' - they are not idiomatic (most java code doesn't work this way; making public fields therefore makes your code look weird), fields do not participate in inheritance (you cannot declare via an interface that any classes that implement it expose some field. fields cannot be overridden), and you cannot mock them or otherwise virtualize or abstract their nature.

### So why is System.out done this way?

History. If java had 'fixed' this error, then any code written that reads from sysin or writes to sysout or syserr would no longer compile in whatever version of java 'fixed' this. Some language do this. Java is institutionally very hesitant to do this ('breaking backwards compatibility'). Doing so leads to projects sticking to old versions and fracturing the community. Imagine you wrote a popular java library. You'd have to publish it for 18 separate java versions, it'd be quite the mess.

Answer (score 1):

**Structure of System.out.println:**

```
public final class System {
    static PrintStream out;
    static PrintStream err;
    static InputStream in;
    ...
}

public class PrintStream extends FilterOutputStream {
    //out object is inherited from FilterOutputStream class
    public void println() {
    ...
}
```

The following explanation of `System.out.println();` given below:

1. `System` is a final class in `java.lang package`.
2. `out` is a static member field of System class and is of `PrintStream` type.
3. `println` is a method of `PrintStream` class.

**Note:** `System.out.println();` is used to print on console. Similarly `System.in` is a standard `InputStream` which is connected to the keyboard input of console programs.

Answer (score 0):

Good that you are learning JAVA.

I hope these links helps you to understand more about your question.

- [Static Methods](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-java/flow/methods/50static-methods.html)
- [System Class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-lang-system-class-java/)
- [About System.in and System.out](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/system-in-out-error.html)